# What is the meaning of (HR) (LY) (FOR) in radio phraseology?

Tags: radio-communications, phraseology, radio

Need help!

Can’f figure out what’s the meaning of (HR) (LY) (FOR) beside some words from this document:  [Source](https://files.fpz.hr/Djelatnici/ifrancetic/Radiotelephony-communications-1-handbook.pdf).

[image]

Comment: source document: https://files.fpz.hr/Djelatnici/ifrancetic/Radiotelephony-communications-1-handbook.pdf

Comment: @tedder42, good on ya for finding the source, saved the OP a possible DV and multiple questions!  Anyway, I put a link in the question itself...

Answer (score 4):

"LY" and "FOR" are simply optional suffixes. In other words, "immediate" can be "immediately".

"HR" can only be determined from inference: this is a Croatian document, "HR" is the country code for Croatia (*Hrvatska*).

Comment: More explicitly, the (HR) entries appear to be local additions (or non-exclusions) that are not found in ICAO 10/II/5.2.1.5.8

Comment: they aren't all italicized, eg airborne, read.

Comment: No, they're not all italicized.   But checking against the ICAO document, none of the (HR) entries are listed (including Airborne and Read).